# Cant find page - SQL ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, perl

Trying to migrate an existing [SITE ONE](http://mystudentloans.info/) - to my local server [SITE TWO](http://etkhost1.com/)

but getting this error.

please help

> [Fri Apr 24 04:17:08 2015] [error] [client 59.96.252.161] [Fri Apr 24
>   04:17:08 2015] t.pl: Can't locate Mysql/Statement.pm in @INC (@INC
>   contains: . /home/etkhost1/perl5/lib/perl5
>   /home/etkhost1/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /home/etkhost1/perl/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux
>   /home/etkhost1/perl/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8
>   /home/etkhost1/perl/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux
>   /home/etkhost1/perl/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
>   /home/etkhost1/perl/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl)
>   at Mysql.pm line 12.

```
sub info {
    my $q = new CGI;
    my $db = Mysql->connect('localhost','X','Y','Z');
        my $filing_status = $postFields{ "filing_status" };
        my $street_address = $postFields{ "street_address" };
        my $country = $postFields{ "country" };
        my $po_box = $postFields{ "po_box" };
        my $apt = $postFields{ "apt" };
        my $city = $postFields{ "city" };
        my $state = $postFields{ "state" };
        my $zip = $postFields{ "zip" };
```

Comment: That's not a SQL error.  That's Perl griping that it can't find a library (a Perl module) that should have a filename of **`Statement.pm`**.  Perl is trying to resolve a reference to that, found on line 12 of **`Mysql.pm`**.  The list of directories that Perl searches is given in `@INC`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look deeper into it. We don't really have access to the original files so it was hard to tell what is what.

Comment: I hope that's not your real database username and password in the code snippet. If so, I would recommend changing your password, just to be safe.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - It is wrong compare to what they created - thats why I didn't change it, but regardless I've updated it all - Thanks for the note

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install [`DBD::mysql`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql)

---

**Update**

`@ThisSuitIsBlackNot` points out that the most recent version of `DBD::mysql` doesn't contain the `Mysql` module. You can fix that by [downloading version 3.0008](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-) and installing it manually. Instructions for installing modules are in [`perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html3.0008.tar.gz)

Comment: @Nettrus: The code that you have posted doesn't really help. You need to install `DBD::mysql`

Comment: @Borodin Installing `DBD::mysql` by itself won't solve the problem because (based on the posted code) the script isn't using the `DBI` module.  It's using the outdated `Mysql` module, which I can't seem to find right now.  So, the OP will also need to install the DBI module and adjust the script accordingly.

Comment: Makes sence - this was about to turn into a nightmare to us. The owner of the code can't really explain anything and the original developer vanished off the map.

Comment: @RonBergin: I understood that `Mysql` had become a part of `DBD::mysql` and [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-3.0008/lib/Mysql.pm) agrees, saying *"As of Msql-Mysql-modules 1.19_10 M(y)sqlPerl is no longer a separate module. Instead it is emulated using the DBI drivers."* However I can't find any trace of a `Mysql.pm` in the current version of the module

Comment: @Nettrus: I am more than happy to sort things out for you if you wish. Email me at borodin@trashmail.com to discuss. It's a temporary email address that will expire in three days

Comment: Mysql.pm was dropped from the DBD::mysql distribution in the 4.0 release (December, 2006).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:  Ah, thanks. I guess installing an older version of the module would work